# Swift regex - How to extract a matching group

Tags: regex, swift

This is a question about Regular Expressions in Swift.  I have found various tutorials that mention how to do searching and matching but nothing about grouping:

Here is a simple Match statement:

```
if Regex("\\w{4}").test("ABCD") {
  println("matches pattern")
}
```

But what if i wanted to extract the 3rd letter:

```
if Regex("\\w{2}(\\w)\\w").text("REGX") {
   print("Found a match with \$1")
}
```

What is the correct syntax to print matching groups?

Or more specifically - how would I extract **2044** from `2014-10-29T20:44:00`

Comment: You can just skips the groups and use a look behind and look ahead `(?<=\w{2})\w(?=\w)`.

Comment: @DanielGimenez wouldn't work in this case (without extra cleansing), because OP wants `2044` from `2014-10-29T20:44:00`.

Comment: @Sam question was edited after my post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `NSRegularExpression`.

```
var pattern = ".+T(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d).+"
var string = "2014-10-29T20:44:00"

var error: NSError? = nil

var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators, error: &error)


var result = regex?.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSRange(location:0,
    length:countElements(string)), withTemplate: "$1$2")
```

I would be inclined to do this without regular expressions, though:

```
var charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "T:") 

var array =
string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet) 

var result2 =
"\(array[1])\(array[2])"
```

This breaks the datetime string to array of substrings separated by either T or : and I get the hours and minutes in second and third element of the returned array.

Comment: How do I get time i-e hr/min/sec if string is like "PT1H22M33S"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer in Swift 5.7 using Regex literal:

```
if let match = try /\w{2}(\w)\w/.wholeMatch(in: "REGX") {
    print("Found a match with \(match.1)") // prints 'G'
}
```

`match.1` is the value in the first capture group.